# How to re-generate yocto SDK in deploy folder

Tags: sdk, yocto, populate, bitbake

First time, I use the command

```
$ bitbake machine-image -c populate_sdk
```

all process success, and then generated the SDK shell script `xxx.sh` in the deploy folder.

Then, I want to add a new recipe into the project, then bake it successfully. Next I would like to generate new SDK again, so I delete the SDK folder under deploy, bitbake again, all process success, but NOTHING generated, even I rebake and rebake image, SDK would not generated.

message like:

```
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3760 tasks of which 3760 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

How can I trigger the **`re-populate`** processes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As all the files already generated during your first execution and yocto decides based on time stamp/sstate cache, it is not willing to re-do the same compilation again. Also yocto doesn't track the files in `tmp/deploy/sdk/`.

One quick solution could be to use `--force`, for example

```
bitbake machine-image -c populate_sdk -f
```

this invalidates the time stamp and re-run the populate sdk command alone again.

Comment: Awesome, that's it. it's useful parameter "-f",  thanks Parthiban.

Comment: Accept the answer if it addresses your question :-)